# Cannot detect number with OCR

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I try to get the number and it's position in the image using Azure Cognitive Services OCR but it cannot detect any number in the image. Here is the [Image that I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhIzq.jpg). (I'm using a sample code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts/csharp )

Thank you,
Art

Answer (score 2):

That is a known problem for Microsoft and Goolge cloud OCR - they fail on isolated characters while working well on longer lines of text. You may consider alternative cloud OCR services, for example this one: http://ocrsdk.com It works perfectly on image you provided.

Disclaimer: I work for ABBYY.